# Which type of ArrayList is used to store Drawable variables in android

Tags: android

In my app I want to store list of app icons in `ArrayList`. Here is my code from where I get the app icons images:

```
for(String a:array){ //array contains list of appplications package name
    try{
        Drawable icon=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(a);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here, I want to store all the app icons which is getting from `icon` variable into a `ArrayList`. But how to store all the app icon images in `ArrayList` because my icons are generating at run time.
So, how can I add all the Drawable `icons` into a ArrayList- any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create your own `ArrayList<Drawable>` and populate as follows:

```
final List<Drawable> icons = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
final PackageManager mgr = getPackageManager();
for (final String app : array) {
    try {
        final Drawable icon = mgr.getApplicationIcon(app);
        icons.add(icon);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
/* now we have our icon Drawables in a list */
```

Comment: ok your code is correct.Now I can store the icons in Drawable ArrayList.One more question how can I use that Drawable Arraylist with listView.So that I can display the icons via ListView

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below... This way, you can store/retrieve the drawable by a key (which is the package name)

```
HashMap<String,Drawable> drawableList = new HashMap<String,Drawable>();
for(String a:array){ //array contains list of appplications package name
    try{
        Drawable icon=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(a);
        drawableList.put(a, icon);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Or, you can use ArraList and store only the drawables:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> drawableList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
for(String a:array){ //array contains list of appplications package name
    try{
        Drawable icon=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(a);
        drawableList.add(icon);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```